# Correct syntax using 'as well as'

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I have the feeling that this sentence is not correct and that it would be better to split it in two, but I can't seem to get my head around it. I would appreciate any hints as to whether it is a correct grammatical sentence in the first place.

'Books offer a major learning curve as well as sharing some general ideas.'

Comment: Can **sharing some general ideas** be an object of the verb to **offer**?

Comment: @Rathony it's meant to be a sentence Adjunct, I think. I had the same parsing issue when I read the sentence too (see my answer below).

Comment: @Rathony Yes. Nor, I would argue, can *a major learning curve*. What is a *leaning curve*? It is not something that is given and received, nor offered. It is a graphical representation of the rate at which people learn. Better to say * Books offer learning opportunities as well as general ideas*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is fine. However, personally I find the sentence difficult to parse easily because the *as well as* makes me think that it is going to be followed by something else that is offered, not something else that books do. In other words it's easy to try and parse the sentence like this:

- Books offer [**a major learning curve** [as well as **sharing some general ideas**]].

However, it's clear that you need the sentence to be read as:

- [**Books offer a major learning curve**], [as well as (**them) sharing some general ideas**].

In cases like this it might be better to move the *as well as* Adjunct to the front of the sentence to avoid this problem:

- As well as sharing some general ideas, books offer a major learning curve.

In my opinion, the sentence would be improved if it stated who the ideas were shared with and who was being offered an improved learning curve:

- As well as helping people share ideas, books offer readers a more rapid learning curve.

Something like that, anyhow.

Comment: I couldn't put my finger on what was wrong with the sentence, but that was it indeed. Thank you.

Comment: Another ex cathedra proclamation. I've seen this usage of 'as well as'   labelled as wrong by some commentators.

Comment: @Araucaria I agree it's syntactically okay, but I'd parse it differently to you. "As well as" is not introducing a coordinate element here, but a subordinate one. The constituents are not coordinates (they are syntactically unlike: _offer a major learning curve_ is a finite VP and _sharing some general ideas_ a gerund-participial, meaning that “as well as” can’t be a kind of compound coordinator. I see the GP as complement to the second "as” and the whole sequence _as well as sharing some general ideas_ as an adjunct. That's how I'd parse it.

Comment: @BillJ Oh, in my editing and reediting my point got misconstrued  there by my bracketing. I didn't mean to imply that there was any coordination, I was just trying to show that the "sharing.." might be interpreted as "offered in addition to books"  as opposed to as a sentence Adjunct (which is what my post says it is). Thanks. Let me ponder how to diagram it properly ....

Comment: @BillJ Is that bracketing any less misleading there now?

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, that's how I see it.